# After I submit the data, the form is not cleaned although the line to do this is present

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having a problem with my code.

When I submit the data, the form is not cleaned although the line to do this is present (as seen from the code below).

```js
function easyHTTP() {
            this.http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        easyHTTP.prototype.put = function (url, data, callback) {

            this.http.open('PUT', url, true);
            this.http.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
            this.http.setRequestHeader('access-control-allow-methods', 'PUT');

            this.http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');

            d1 = JSON.stringify(data);
            console.log(d1)
            this.http.send(d1);
        }


        function myFunction() {

                                
            const data = {
                id: document.getElementById('id').value,
                data: document.getElementById('date').value,
                immagine: document.getElementById('image').value,
                marca: document.getElementById('brand').value,
                titolo: document.getElementById('title').value
            };

            const http = new easyHTTP;

            // Put prototype method(url, data, response text)
            http.put('https://2hgtrsoxk6.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/articles',
                data, function (err, post) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    } else {
                        console.log(post);
                    }
                });
            document.getElementById("save").value = "";
        }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <form method="post" id="save" action="javascript:myFunction()">
            <div class="field">
                <label for="id">ID :</label>
                <input type="text" id="id" name="id" />
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <label for="data">Data:</label>
                <input type="text" id="date" name="date" />
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <label for="immagine">Immagine:</label>
                <input type="file" id="image" name="image" />
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <label for="marca">Marca:</label>
                <input type="text" id="brand" name="brand" />
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <label for="titolo">Titolo:</label>
                <input type="text" id="title" name="title" />
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <button type="submit" class="full">Save</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Can anyone explain to me why the form cleaning is not performed despite having put document.getElementById("save").value=""; in the function myFunction??

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
document.getElementById("save").value = ''
```

with

```
document.getElementById("save").reset();
```

[`.reset()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset) is a method that allows you to trigger a `"reset"` event on a `<form>` programmatically. The standard `"reset"` event happens when the user clicks a reset button

```
 <button type='reset'>CLEAR</button>
 <!--- OR --->
 <input type='reset' value='CLEAR'>
```

```js
function easyHTTP() {
            this.http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        easyHTTP.prototype.put = function (url, data, callback) {

            this.http.open('PUT', url, true);
            this.http.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
            this.http.setRequestHeader('access-control-allow-methods', 'PUT');

            this.http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');

            d1 = JSON.stringify(data);
            console.log(d1)
            this.http.send(d1);
        }


        function myFunction() {

                                
            const data = {
                id: document.getElementById('id').value,
                data: document.getElementById('date').value,
                immagine: document.getElementById('image').value,
                marca: document.getElementById('brand').value,
                titolo: document.getElementById('title').value
            };

            const http = new easyHTTP;

            // Put prototype method(url, data, response text)
            http.put('https://2hgtrsoxk6.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/articles',
                data, function (err, post) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    } else {
                        console.log(post);
                    }
                });
            document.getElementById("save").reset();
        }
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <form method="post" id="save" action="javascript:myFunction()">
            <div class="field">
                <label for="id">ID :</label>
                <input type="text" id="id" name="id" />
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <label for="data">Data:</label>
                <input type="text" id="date" name="date" />
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <label for="immagine">Immagine:</label>
                <input type="file" id="image" name="image" />
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <label for="marca">Marca:</label>
                <input type="text" id="brand" name="brand" />
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <label for="titolo">Titolo:</label>
                <input type="text" id="title" name="title" />
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <button type="submit" class="full">Save</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The line `document.getElementById("save").value = "";` isn't going to clean the form because forms don't have a value. The value is only in the inputs.

You would need something like this:

```
document.getElementById("save")
    .querySelectorAll('input')
    .forEach(function(input) {input.value = ""})
```

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't work. I get the "Syntax Error" error on the "arrow".

Comment: Honestly if you're getting a syntax error on the arrow, you're on a browser that's more than 7 years old. You can always replace those arrows with a `function`, but I would recommend using a newer browser. It will help with almost everything. https://caniuse.com/arrow-functions

Comment: I use IE, maybe that's the problem. I used to use Chrome, but unfortunately the latter was giving me CORS problems and I am using IE for this reason. Can you recommend a better browser to test the codes and all?

Comment: Chrome or firefox. Try `document.getElementById("save").reset()` instead.